# Which ng-grid triggered the ngGridEventEndCellEdit?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have two ng-grids living in the same `$scope`, they both have a column of editable cells, ie: `enableCellEdit: true`

I know I can handle the triggered event like this:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(event) { 
    var product = event.targetScope.row.entity;

    console.log(product);
});
```

Question is.. how do I know which grid triggered the event? both grids consume different lists (`data` attribute of the grid), but these lists contains instances of the same type.

Is there any property inside `event` that contains the id of the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble and worked around it.

I have three grids and on each cellEditableTemplate I register the ng-click on the cell, thus selecting the next source of the start and end event of the cell edit. The `setMethod()` that just sets the global variable `$scope.thisGridUpdate`

```
$scope.targetTypeDefs = [ {
    field : 'id',
    displayName : '#',
    enableCellEdit : false,
    width : 50
}, {
    field : 'desc',
    displayName : 'Type Description',
    enableCellEdit : true,
    cellEditableCondition : 'row.selected',
        editableCellTemplate : '<input ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" \
            ng-input="COL_FIELD" \
            ng-model="COL_FIELD" \
            ng-model-options="{ updateOn : \'default blur\' }" \
            ng-click="setMethod(\'saveTargetType\')"/>'
} ];
$scope.targetTypeGrid = {
    data : 'targetTypeData',
    showSelectionCheckbox : true,
    selectWithCheckboxOnly : true,
    multiSelect : false,
    enableCellEditOnFocus : true,
    columnDefs : 'targetTypeDefs'
};
```

Next you just catch and trap the end cell edit events in your normal `ngGridEventEndCellEdit` event consumer, like this:

```
$scope.setMethod = function(name) {
    console.log("clicked on ", name);
    $scope.thisGridUpdate = name;
};
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(evt, other) {
    console.log("ended edit on ", $scope.thisGridUpdate, "with " , evt.targetScope.row.entity);
    console.log(evt.targetScope.row);
    if ($scope.thisGridUpdate === 'saveServerType') {
        EntityMgt.saveServerType(evt.targetScope.row.entity);
    }
    else if ($scope.thisGridUpdate === 'saveOsVersion') {
        EntityMgt.saveOsVersion(evt.targetScope.row.entity);
    }
    else if ($scope.thisGridUpdate === 'saveTargetType') {
        EntityMgt.saveTargetType(evt.targetScope.row.entity);
    }
});
```